# Send image to web server and receive information

Tags: android, image, send

I am new to android and java so please bear with me with the incorrect terms used. I am programming an application that helps to identify the location with an image.

1. Capture image from camera
2. Send captured image to a web server
3. Listen and receive information from the web server regarding the location of the captured image and display to user.

Hence main problems are:

- Send image to web server
- Receive information from web server

Comment: This may be a useful starting point for your research: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/phototours/

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, my main problems for now are sending of image to web server and receive information (probably like a string) from the server.

Comment: You should web service to send data to web server as request & get that details as response after identifying the image of particular place.

Comment: Hello Devin,

I have to develop a similar program my android app needs to send data to the server and receive response from the web server. Also, the web server can send command request to the android app. 

I am new to Java web server and android too.. need some suggestion on proceedings.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: hi delvin I'm new in Android. I 'm trying to make the same application that u made. can u send me some suggestion and example codes? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method (which i got from somewhere, but dont know where from), it works for me:

```
private void doFileUpload() {

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; //size of your image
    String responseFromServer = "";
    String urlString = "http://yourwebserver/receiver.php";

    try {
        // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                mFileName));
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                + mFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        // create a buffer of maximum size
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        // close streams
        Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }
    // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
    try {
        inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        String str;
        while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
        }
        inStream.close();
    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
    }
}
```

The file will in $_FILES array on your webserver.